# Show the structure of the table in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlplus

Can someone explain things a little better to me? How do I show the structure of a table? 
I run the `select * from table`; and of course it displays all that's in the table. But, I am being asked to show the structure of the table. What does that mean, and what is the command?

Here's my table below.

```
SQL> select * from dept;

DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
    10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
    20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
    30 SALES          CHICAGO
    40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

 SQL>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To list columns and data types, I typically use

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='your_table_name';
```

It's been a while since I've worked with Oracle though.  `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` might actually be `ALL_TAB_COLS`.

If you need to display the full `CREATE TABLE` statement, see [How to get Oracle create table statement in SQL*Plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937398/how-to-get-oracle-create-table-statement-in-sqlplus)

Comment: Its just not clicking for me.

Comment: @user770022 Yes, I believe `DESCRIBE` is supported in Oracle as well.

Answer (score 22):

Try this out: `describe table_name`

Comment: Or `desc table_name` but It works with Oracle and not with MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sqlplus command `describe <SCHEMA_OWNER.TABLE>`

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12019.htm