# Oracle Datatype Modifier

Tags: oracle, types, modifier

I need to be able to reconstruct a table column by using the column data in DBA_TAB_COLUMNS, and so to develop this I need to understand what each column refers to. I'm looking to understand what DATA_TYPE_MOD is -- the documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm#I1020277) says it is a data type modifier, but I can't seem to find any columns with this field populated or any way to populate this field with a dummy column. Anyone familiar with this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Data_type_mod` column of the `[all][dba][user]_tab_columns` data dictionary view gets populated when a column of a table is declared as a reference to an object type using `REF` datatype(contains object identifier(OID) of an object it points to).

```
  create type obj as object(
    item number
  ) ;

  create table tb_1(
    col ref obj
  )


  select t.table_name
       , t.column_name
       , t.data_type_mod
   from user_tab_columns t
  where t.table_name = 'TB_1'
```

Result:

```
table_name   column_name   data_type_mod
-----------------------------------------
TB_1         COL           REF
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a PL/SQL package that can be used to generate the DDL for creating a table.  You would probably be better off using this.

See GET_DDL on http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#i1019414

And see also:
[How to get Oracle create table statement in SQL*Plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937398/how-to-get-oracle-create-table-statement-in-sqlplus)

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this package. The reason I need to understand these columns is so that when I am adding a column or modifying an existing column I do not need to drop and create the table, I can just run an ALTER. I can generate the alter by comparing columns of DBA_TAB_COLUMNS and data in my own custom table storing all table columns.